# How to bind Image field to PictureBox in VB.Net 2008

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado.net, bind, picturebox

I have a table with image field that I need to bind to System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox, and I need to Load new images o Overwrite existing images or delete the image int the field with ADO.NET dataset object.

Comment: It's a big, wide question. Is there a specific part that's giving you trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this code in the Form_Load Event :

```
Me.picCaptured.DataBindings.Add("Image", mbsPrimario, "PICFIELD", True, _
  Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
```

and Work Ok.