# C# WinForms: How to binding a PictureBox to DataGridView

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview, parent-child, picturebox

In C# WinForms, I have a DataGridView which DataSource is a DataSet, and has a column "Picture" which contains images.

**Now my question is:**

How do I use data binding to a PictureBox, so everytime I click in a row from the DataGridView, my PictureBox shows the image from the "Picture" column on my DataGridView?

Comment: @GrantWinney Sorry forgot to mention, its WinForms

Comment: Found it [How to bind Image field to PictureBox in VB.Net 2008][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638938/how-to-bind-image-field-to-picturebox-in-vb-net-2008

problem solved